# How to calculate $\frac{8\sin^3(10^o)+1}{2\sin10^o}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I need a hint.

I tried this but it didn't lead me very far.
$\frac{8\sin^3(10^o)+1}{2\sin10^o} = \frac{(2\sin10^o + 1)(4\sin^210^o-2\sin10^o + 1)}{2\sin10^o}$

How should I approach this?

*By the way* I inputed the expression into wolframalpha and it turns out
$\frac{8\sin^3(10^o)+1}{2\sin10^o} = 3$
But that doesn't tell me how to get to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you only require a *hint*,

Use that $$\sin 3x=3\sin x- 4\sin^3 x$$
$$\implies \sin^3 x=\frac{3\sin x-\sin 3x}{4}$$
Use this to find out $8\sin^310^\circ$ and see what happens when you substitute it in your expression.

Comment: Very smart approach +1.

Comment: Oh that's beautiful, especially that $\sin3x=\sin30^o=\frac{1}{2}$. Thank you!